# How to define Custom js in Custom module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom-options

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer' : 'Wac_SwatchName/js/swatch-renderer',
            'magento-swatch.renderer' : 'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer',
            'CustomName' : 'Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom',
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js

```
$(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() {
 alert('test');
}
```

Only My Custom Js file Works When my Custom module load, But now Custom js not loading Properly ,Please  Check my custom js file and requirejs-config file

Comment: Remove the path view/frontend/web

Comment: correct it : 'CustomName' : 'Vendor_Module/js/custom'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call correct module name and file name in requirejs-config.js

```
  "CustomName": "Vendor_Module/js/custom"
```

Need to declare require method in custom.js

```
require([
    "jquery"
], function($) {
$(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() {
alert('test');
});
});
```

Comment: Is it working fine?

Comment: clear generated folder

Comment: rm -rf var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ generated/